# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}x^n,$ at the point $x=e$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to check the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}x^n,$$at the point $x=e$. I feel that the $n$-th term $a_n=\frac{n! (e/n)^n}{(1+1/n)^n}$ is not convergent. But I couldn't find some estimate $b_n$ such that $b_n \leq a_n$ and $\lim b_n >0$.

Or

Anything like $c_n$ such that $a_n \leq c_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\lim c_n=0$ is possible? if so how to prove the convergence?

Comment: Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation.

Comment: Try to take $b_n=1$. $a_1 > b_1$, $a_{n+1}/a_{n}>1$.

Comment: How can we show that $(n+1/n+2)^{n+1}e>1$?